# the speed of a "for loop" in python populating a list is getting slower with each iteration

Tags: python, list, performance, loops, for-loop

I am populating a large list of list in python using for loop:

With each iteration, the speed is getting slower and slower.

```py
tdif=[0]*316
for i in tnrange(len(list_ngrams2)):
    store=[]
    for value in list_ngrams2[i]:  
        if  value in features:
            store.append(value)
    tdif[i]=store
```

List comprehension has the same problem:

```py
tdif=[value for lst in list_ngrams2 for value in lst if value in features]
```

[Run-time analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVEq9.png)

So how to speed it up?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8TLV.png)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how it is possible to speed it up?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information to help. What is `list_ngrams2`, what is `tqdm` and what is `features`? Do you absolutely need `tdif` as a list? Your for loop and list comprehensions aren't even equivalent (`np.array` is called in the latter).

Comment: list_ngrams2 is list of lists of 3 grams (tuples). I want to create the same list of list of tuples, but only those, which are contained in the list of features.

Comment: @RobStreeting It is set by the `for` loop. I suspect the `tnrange()` should read just `range()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressed as list comprehension(s) – assuming that it doesn't need to be limited or padded to 316 elements in `tdif`:

```
features_set = set(features)
tdif = [
    [value for value in values if value in features_set]
    for values in list_ngrams2
]
```